# Storing multiple data values different Tables as a single value in parent table - DB relationships

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm having a issue with with my database organisation, i'm a bit messed up with. Probably something easy who knows. Question is what is better:
- having all data values seperated in the parent tables   or
- can I join the 3 values as one single value in parent tables?

My case is:

Table Countries:
Country ID - Name

Table Regions:
Region ID - Name

Table Cities:
City iD - Name

Table Companies:
Company ID - Name - City - Region - Country - etc

OR can I :

Table Countries:
Country ID - Name

Table Regions:
Region ID - Name

Table Cities:
City ID  Region Country

and then table cities as a single value in
Table companies:
Company ID - Name - City(city-region-country) - etc

Thanks for your help!

Greets,

Jonathan

Comment: Hi. Time to read a textbook on information modeling, the relational model & database design. (Nb--A manual for a design tool, api or language to record designs is not a manual/tutorial on design.) PS This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think the second approach is better because there is a big chance of making your data inconsistent with the first one. Also if you wanna change for example the RegionID of NYC, you will have to make it in one place. 
Hint - I think the name of a table should not be in plural form, because of many reasons. If you want I can describe them.
So i think you should have the following tables: Country, Region, City and Company and all your FK's should end with ID. For example City should have RegionID and CityID.